# Calculus II: Infinite Series Convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

So I'm trying to test for convergence with infinite series. I know how to use the ratio rule when it gives me a clear $r$ value to plug in, but for this specific problem I know you have to take the limit. Just not sure how to set it up completely.

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+3)(k+2)}$$

Comment: Observe that $$\frac{1}{(k+3)k+2)} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$ What can you say about $\sum (1/k^2)$?

Comment: This is a telescoping sum, so it converges, and the sum is $1/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{(k+3)(k+2)} < \frac{1}{k^2}.$ You remember the comparison test, right?

Comment: I don't think it goes over that in this section of my math book. The way the solution manual does it is like this: Sn sum from 1 to n 1/(k+2) -1/(k+3)